How can I control output of the special parameter * in conditional expressions in bash?
I have a filename fofo.l stored in the variable FI. I want to check for ".l" in the file name. If so, command1 is executed. If not, command2 is executed.
I used set -x and tried:
if test $FI == *.l*; then echo done; else echo fail; fi 

this is the output:
+ test fofo.l == esc.txt execve.c fofo. fofo.l foo1.cpp foo2.c foo.c foo.gz foo.l fool.sl foo.save foo.sl foo.xz goo.xz goo.xz.orig mprint.c myecho2.c myecho.c nano.10558.save p1.c pm.c pm.o term.cpp zipT.gz
bash: test: too many arguments
+ echo fail
fail

As far as I know, bash just replaces * with any amount of characters. There are plenty of matching files. How can I solve this problem?

Try case $FI in *.l*) echo done;; *) echo fail; esac

note there's a difference between ending with foo.l, containing test.list.txt, and the extension starting with foo.la which you may want to consider

OP is tagged with bash.
If you are using bash and do not need to worry about portability, then there is almost never a reason to use test (or [) - just make a habit of using [[...]] (and rather than expr or let, prefer ((...)) for arithmetic evaluations.)
See Conditional Constructs for details.
On the CLI, test doesn't change your context, so "globs" (*) are processed with filename expansion and replaced by the list of all matches, which is generating too many arguments for test.
There are a lot of ways to check strings and files in bash, and some will overlap. As has been mentioned in comments, both [[ and case constructs will use globbing without word splitting or pathname expansion.
Given f=fofo.l and x=abcd,
$: dotl(){ [[ $1 == *.l* ]] && echo match || echo nope; }
$: dotl $f
match
$: dotl $x
nope

$: dotl(){ case $1 in *.l*) echo match;; *) echo nope;; esac; }
$: dotl $f
match
$: dotl $x
nope

If you prefer an actual regex -
$: dotl(){ [[ $1 =~ [.]l ]] && echo match || echo nope; }
$: dotl $f
match
$: dotl $x
nope

If you need portability, and high performance isn't a major concern, there are plenty of widely available programs to which you could farm the test out - grep is the usual go-to for this sort of thing.
$: dotl(){ echo $1 | if grep -q '[.]l'; then echo match; else echo nope; fi; }
$: dotl $f
match
$: dotl $x
nope

If you're just fond of odd structures you can even do "tricks" like this with basic Parameter Expansion (though I generally don't recommend it):
$: dotl(){ local tst=${1/#*.l*/}; echo "$1 contains ${tst:+NO }.l"; }
$: dotl fofo.l
fofo.l contains .l
$: dotl ooo.lala
ooo.lala contains .l
$: dotl abcd
abcd contains NO .l

Maybe it's an X/Y Problem, and you're asking how to tell if a file has a given string because you plan to walk through all files and do something with each one if it matches - so what you really want is the list of the files that match, instead of the test for each file.
For that, a glob handles it all at once:
$: touch fofo.l ooo.lala abcd

$: echo *
abcd fofo.l ooo.lala

$: echo "Files with '.l':" *.l*
fofo.l ooo.lala

$: for f in *.l*; do echo ${f^^}; done
FOFO.L
OOO.LALA

And just for another take on it, maybe a lookup table will help.
$: . <( lst=(*.l*); shopt -s patsub_replacement; echo "declare -A lookup=(${lst[@]//*/[&]=1})" )
$: declare -p lookup # lst inside is scoped to the subshell; use outside to keep
declare -A lookup=([ooo.lala]="1" [fofo.l]="1" )

$: echo "There are ${#lookup[@]} Files with '.l': ${!lookup[@]}"
There are 2 Files with '.l': ooo.lala fofo.l

$: for f in *; do [[ -n "${lookup[$f]}" ]] && echo "$f contains .l" || echo "$f does not contain .l"; done
abcd does not contain .l
fofo.l contains .l
ooo.lala contains .l

Just be sure to test your chosen method against some of the oddest and least-likely use-cases that might actually happen. Filenames can have embedded spaces, including even newlines, carriage returns, and/or control characters like backspace, the bell, or an end-of-file marker.

Wildcard expansion is for finding names of files in the actual file system. To test whether a string contains characters you are interested in, you can use the regular expression matching operator, =~:
#!/bin/bash -e

function TestIt
{
    if [[ $1 =~ \.l ]]; then
        echo "$1 contains \".l\"."
    else
        echo "$1 does not contain \".l\"."
    fi
}

TestIt "fofo.l"
TestIt ".l"
TestIt "foo.landmore"
TestIt "xl"
TestIt "fofoxl"

This outputs:

fofo.l contains ".l".
.l contains ".l".
foo.landmore contains ".l".
xl does not contain ".l".
fofoxl does not contain ".l".


Wildcard expansion is for finding names of files in the actual file system. Not only. In this case =~ is not needed. [[ $FI == *.l* ]] is enough because there is no word splitting and no pathname expansion in conditional expressions and pattern matching is used for ==. If I remember well it should even work with older bash versions than =~.

@RenaudPacalet: Yes, but it only works in bash and in [[ ... ]], i.e. not in other shells and not in [ ... ] or test.
